# Pandas Series replacement values using index

Tags: python, pandas, variable-assignment, slice, series

I am trying to assign to new values to the existing series based on index.  But the behavior is not as I expect.  Below is a dummy code that reproduced the result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.Series(range(10))
y = pd.Series(range(10, 20))
ind = np.random.permutation(range(10))

x
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9

y

0    10
1    11
2    12
3    13
4    14
5    15
6    16
7    17
8    18
9    19

ind
array([0, 9, 8, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5, 2, 1])

x[ind] = y[ind]  #try to assign based on identical index 
x
```

I am expecting to get the following for x.

```
0    10
1    11
2    12
3    13
4    14
5    15
6    16
7    17
8    18
9    19
```

Instead, I got

```
0    10
1    19
2    18
3    17
4    13
5    16
6    14
7    15
8    12
9    11
```

Basically, it assigned y[ind] to x and ignored the indexes.  Am I doing something wrong?  If the ind does not contain the entire data from x, the assignment appears to be correct.

Looks like it is a bug in 0.13.0 and 0.13.1.  Fixed in development version

Answer (score 2):

I tried the code you posted and I got the result you expected for x:

```
0    10
1    11
2    12
3    13
4    14
5    15
6    16
7    17
8    18
9    19
```

Maybe you are using a older version of pandas?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I am using '0.13.0'

Comment: hmm, yours is actually newer than mine. mine pandas version is "0.12.0", python version "2.7.6", and ipython version "1.1.0". A bug in the new version?

Comment: Just tested on 0.13.1 on another computer, it still generated the same result.  My python version is 2.7.3.

Comment: IIRC this was a bug in 0.13.0, fixed in 0.13.1 (only shows up in some very special cases).

Comment: It does not appears to be fixed in the pip installed version, but it is fixed in the github developmental version of pandas.  Thanks!